# Access SQL Update Case using RIGHT() function

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to modify the last character of a column depending on what this character is. So far, the best method I've come to is to use the Update Case with the Right() function, but it doesn't work, when I execute it I've got an error telling me I'm missing an operator and I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's my code :

```
UPDATE Import 
SET MONTANT = 
( 
CASE WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='é' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '0' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='{' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '0' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='A' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '1' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='B' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '2' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='C' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '3' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='D' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '4' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='E' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '5' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='F' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '6' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='G' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '7' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='H' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '8' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='I' THEN Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '9' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='è' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '0' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='}' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '0' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='J' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '1' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='K' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '2' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='L' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '3' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='M' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '4' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='N' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '5' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='O' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '6' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='P' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '7' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='Q' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '8' 
WHEN Right([MONTANT], 1)='R' THEN '-' & Left([MONTANT],LEN([MONTANT])-1) & '9' 
ELSE MONTANT 
END 
)
```

I already tried a few fixes : Using LENGTH instead of LEN doesn't do a thing, using the syntax :

```
CASE Right([MONTANT], 1) WHEN 'é' THEN
```

Following your pieces of advice, i tried the 2 other forms : Using IIF and Using Switch as follows :

```
UPDATE Import 
SET MONTANT = SWITCH(
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='é', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '0',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='{', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '0',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='A', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '1',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='B', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '2',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='C', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '3',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='D', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '4',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='E', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '5', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='F', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '6', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='G', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '7', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='H', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '8', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='I', LEFT(MONTANT, LENGTH(MONTANT) - 1) & '9', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='è', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '0',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='}', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '0',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='J', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '1',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='K', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '2',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='L', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '3',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='M', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '4',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='N', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '5',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='O', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '6',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='P', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '7',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='Q', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '8',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='R', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LENGTH(MONTANT)-1) & '9'
)
```

The issue being that Access also tells me that it's too complicated, maybe i should try doing it in two separate requests... I'm still opened to new ideas that might work

Comment: As long as you don't execute this query as a pass-through query, Microsoft Access will complain `Case When` the statements, which are Transact SQL.

Comment: @UnhandledException OP is likely just trying to do this on a local table in Access. SQL server and T-SQL aren't mentioned, it's a plain dupe imo, Access doesn't do `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Since when does Access support `case when`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm trying to use this request on a table but it only concerns 1 column. The data looks like "01234941283é" each time and i'm trying to modify the é at the end using a table that is represented in the code...

Comment: @UnhandledException how do i do that please ?

Comment: @forpas well i thought it would work using the Case When method but maybe it is inappropriate..

Comment: @M.Emo: TransactSQL is the SQL dialect of the Microsoft SQL Server. Do you use Microsoft SQL Server for your tables, or do you use simple Microsoft Access tables?

Comment: @M.Emo Access does not support case when. You could use `IIF` but in your case it would be very complicated.

Comment: @UnhandledException This code is ment to be executed on Microsoft Access Tables only

Comment: @forpas What would you advise me to do then ?

Comment: How many records will be updated at once? If it wont be many, you could think about writing a procedure which will be called in the query and receives the field as an argument and returns proper result.

Comment: @ErikA: A custom procedure containing a `Select … Case ...` could be more performant, since `Switch` always will evaluate (execute) all provided conditions, even if the first would be `True`. I'm interested in your opinion.

Comment: @UnhandledException That would require you to have SQL server as a backend. Generally, moving the comparison and update to the server frequently offers a performance increase. Access SQL doesn't do any short-circuiting comparisons afaik, so implementing something like that in Access is plain impossible afaik (or requires VBA which nearly always comes with a performance penalty). These string operations are pretty lightweight so it's likely premature optimization anyway.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. I meant to create a custom Access procedure which uses `Select Case` internally and use this procedure in the query instead of the `Switch` construct.

Comment: @UnhandledException Huh? The Access Database Engine doesn't do `SELECT CASE`, you will either have to pass it to a VBA function or another database engine, both come with certain penalties.

Comment: Correct, a custom VBA-procedure is what I meant. Overall it could be more performant than `Switch` calling each condition unnecessarily.

Comment: @UnhandledException I generally recommend against using custom VBA in SQL, because of several issues, among which: performance penalty, doesn't work with ODBC/OLEDB/DAO (so using the query in code becomes a lot harder), requires project to be trusted, adjusting it requires an exclusive lock. I think that outweighs a possible performance benefit, especially if it's all lightweight operations.

Comment: Good arguments. I Agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Switch` instead of `CASE .. WHEN`

A problem that occurs is that Access SQL can't handle functions with a large number of arguments. This is easily resolved by splitting it into pieces:

```
UPDATE Import 
SET MONTANT = 
SWITCH(
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='é', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '0',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='{', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '0',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='A', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '1',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='B', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '2',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='C', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '3',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='D', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '4',
True, SWITCH(
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='E', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '5', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='F', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '6', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='G', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '7', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='H', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '8', 
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='I', LEFT(MONTANT, LEN(MONTANT) - 1) & '9',
True, SWITCH(
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='è', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '0',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='}', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '0',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='J', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '1',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='K', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '2',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='L', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '3',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='M', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '4',
True, SWITCH(
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='N', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '5',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='O', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '6',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='P', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '7',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='Q', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '8',
RIGHT(MONTANT, 1)='R', '-' & LEFT(MONTANT,LEN(MONTANT)-1) & '9',
True, MONTANT
))))
```

I'm also using the `Switch` statements to split this into chunks, if you go for the maximum number of arguments per switch you can get away with less `Switch` functions.

Comment: This solutio worked thank you so much ! Just had to use LEN instead of LENGTH and to put a comma before the last True and it was ok :) I really wish you a great day you saved me thank you sooooo much <3 :)

Comment: @M.Emo Ah, of course, a bit sloppy of me, I've adjusted it for future readers, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

In Access there is no `CASE` support, but you can use `IIF`. 
I tried to put all your conditions in nested `IIF`s but Access found the whole statement too complicated. 
I tried to follow your logic and zipped the code like this:

```
UPDATE Import  
SET MONTANT = 
IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('é', 'è', '{', '}'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('è', '}'), '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '0', 
    IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('A', 'J'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'J', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '1', 
      IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('B', 'K'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'K', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '2', 
        IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('C', 'L'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'L', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '3', 
          IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('D', 'M'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'M', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '4', 
            IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('E', 'N'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'N', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '5', 
              IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('F', 'O'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'O', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '6', 
                IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('G', 'P'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'P', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '7', 
                  IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('H', 'Q'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'Q', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '8', 
                    IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) IN ('I', 'R'), IIF(Right([MONTANT], 1) = 'R', '-', '') & Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1) & '9', MONTANT
))))))))))
```

Since I could not try it with actual data, I only tested its validity. 
So **try with caution**.

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is large and you're interseted in creating a maintainable solution, I would suggest the following:

Add two fields to your `Import` table:

1. UpdateChar as Short Text
2. RemainderString as Short Text

Update the field `UpdateChar` to the `Right([MONTANT], 1)`

Update the field `RemainderString` to `Left([MONTANT], LEN([MONTANT]) - 1)`

Create a new table which contains the update pairs, with two fields:

1. FromChar as Short Text (this will contain the chars: é, {, }, etc.)
2. ToChar as Short Text (this will match with the chars: 0, 1, 2, ...9)

Then in a separate Update query, link the UpdateChar field from the `Import` table to the FromChar field in the update pairs table. Then update the `Montant` field with the string concatenation of RemainderString(Import table) and ToChar(Update pairs table)

Although this involves multiple steps, I find it a much cleaner solution. Especially if you need to add additional characters in the future.